# Memory management of a vector of data-structures

Tags: c++, memory-management, std, stdvector

I have a data-structure which looks like

```
template < class T1, class T2 > struct sometype
{
std::vector < T1 > v1;
std::vector < T2 > v2;
T1 deriv[10];
};
```

I create a vector of data-structures

```
std::vector <sometype <T1, T2>> somevec;
```

My doubt is if I do this

```
somevec.erase(somevec.begin(), somevec.end());
std::vector <sometype <T1, T2>>().swap (somevec);
```

can I reclaim the memory?

Comment: Reclaim *what* memory? And why would you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @CodyGray Reclaim the memory used used by sometype. I want to conserve memory as I am solving a huge problem where I need to temporarily store about 10 million sometypes/core.

Answer (score 3):

You can do better than that:

```
somevec.erase(somevec.begin(), somevec.end());
std::vector <sometype <T1, T2>>().swap (somevec);
```

All you need to do is:

```
std::vector <sometype<T1, T2>>().swap(somevec);
```

This is because you create a temporary which is empty. Then swap the empty content with actual data of `somevec`. The temporary is then destroyed and reclaiming the memory that was allocated with your variable (because the memory was swapped into the temporary).

This is called the **"Shrink to Fit Idiom"**

Comment: Ok. I do not need to do anything special like in the case of multi-dimensional pointers right?

Comment: Should work fine. Because you are shrinking the first dimension to zero. Thus all the other dimensions are gone.